# Trying to convert a script that involves webrtc into async/await failing

Tags: javascript, async-await, webrtc, es6-promise, es6-modules

I am following this [tutorial](https://www.scaledrone.com/blog/webrtc-tutorial-simple-video-chat/) to make webrtc work. I would like to return the streams I get in resolve() to the component I call this  getDrone() from. I created a returnStreamArray() function as a child promise which I tried to add as a then() to the stream to add it to the array, however I am stuck. I would appreciate any directions.

```
     export default function getDrone() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const drone = new Scaledrone('fBAkzbVAOmA2wbU0');
    const roomName = 'observable-room';
    const configuration = {
      iceServers: [
        {
          urls: 'stun:stun.l.google.com:19302'
        }
      ]
    };
    let room;
    let pc;
    const streamArr = [];

   ...
    drone.on('open', error => {
      if (error) {
        console.error(error);
      }
      room = drone.subscribe(roomName);
      room.on('open', error => {
        if (error) {
          onError(error);
        }
      });

     ..

   ..

      pc.ontrack = event => {
        const stream = event.streams[0];

        streamArr.push(stream);
      };

      navigator.mediaDevices
        .getUserMedia({
          audio: true,
          video: true
        })
        .then(stream => {

          streamArr.push(stream);

          stream.getTracks().forEach(track => pc.addTrack(track, stream));
        }, onError)
        .then(returnStreamArray => {
          console.log(stream);
        });
..
..
      });
    }

    function returnStreamArray() {
      return Promise.resolve({
        streamArray: streamArr
      });
    }
```

Comment: 173 lines is a bit much, can you try to trim it down to the essential elements so that the problem can be reproduced in a [MCVE]?

Comment: It seems you've made almost every function `async` - most of which don't even have an `await` let alone any asynchrony - understand the consequences of making a function `async` before blindly doing so ... also, for one example, `startWebRTC` doesn't return anything, so `await startWebRTC(isOfferer);` makes no sense

Comment: Thanks, I simplified the example and got rid of all async/awaits and sticked to promises. I hope this is helpful. Thanks in advance

Comment: The code you've added doesn't make any sense. I suggest reading [using promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises) for help.